# How to close the menu when I click the button?

Tags: android, gridview, menu, menuitem

I use the `GridView` and set to `MultiChoiceModeListener`.

When I select the item from GridView , it will call the `onCreateActionMode` and the  `onActionItemClicked` like the following code.

```
public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub       
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.actionbar_layout, null);
    mActionText = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.action_text);
    mActionText.setText(formatString(fileListView.getCheckedItemCount()));
    mode.setCustomView(v);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);

    return true;
}
```

And the `menu` will show how many item I have select like the following picture.

[image: The item select from Gridview and show on the menu]

When I click the button , it will transmit the item which I have select to a new `Fragment`.

The following code is for `button`

```
download_button = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.download_button) ;

        download_button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

            Fragment fragment = DownloadPage.newInstance(null, null, null, checkedItems) ;
            MainActivity.addFragment(FileBrowserFragment.this, fragment);
            menu.finish(); //can not call menu.finish();

    }
```

**But when it turn to the new `fragment` , the `menu` doesn't disappeared.**

How to close the `menu` when I click the button and turn to the new `fragment`???

Answer (score 0):

Think you are looking for finish(); on ActionMode see this example:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
        // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_delete:
            deleteSelectedItems();
            mode.finish();
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Comment: But if I want to finish by button not the MenuItem ?

Comment: I think you might be missing the point of the action bar's action mode. The idea is you inflate a special action/context menu. If you want to use your own button why use action mode at all?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to finish by button click, register listener to your button and then put the finish() method inside that.

**EDIT**

Try this:

```
   @Override
public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {
    // Respond to clicks on the actions in the CAB
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.menu_delete:


download_button.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

             Fragment fragment = DownloadPage.newInstance(null, null, null, checkedItems) ;
             MainActivity.addFragment(FileBrowserFragment.this, fragment);

    deleteSelectedItems();
            mode.finish();

        }
});


        return true;

}
```

Comment: Sorry...can you explain more ?

Comment: Do you mean setonclicklistener ? i have try , bit it can not call menu.

Comment: but it still have to click the item of menu.